# How to inspect HTTPS traffic of a third-party app on Android 9+

Tags: proxy, troubleshooting, certificates, https, debug

I want to inspect inside HTTPS-encrypted packets that an app is sending. It is not my app, I don't have its source code.

My device is rooted, so I can modify `/system/etc/security/cacert` if needed, for instance to do [man-in-the-middle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack) proxying.

Up to Android 8, one could just install a self-made certificate, but it does not work anymore. I have Android 9, but I can upgrade if needed.

Comment: I've heard good reviews about [this app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.guoshi.httpcanary) in some forums. No personal experience /affiliation

Answer (score 1):

As tipped by @beeshyams, [HttpCanary](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.guoshi.httpcanary) is perfect for this.

You need a rooted device, of course.

HttpCanary takes care of all of the difficult steps (certificate generation and installation) transparently.

It shows a list of requests (filterable by app), and details of each request and response.

The best feature is this overlay showing request while I am using other apps (bottom right):

[image]

Even though the Google Play page says "*HttpCanary core codes are opened in Github*", https://github.com/MegatronKing/HttpCanary does not contain most of the source code, so I believe it is not open source.